# View based ActiveAdmin item displaying errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have my workers view based on users table, and I need separate item in my ActiveAdmin, so I changed default create/update logic to sth like this:

```
    def update
      if params[:worker][:password].blank?
        params[:worker].delete("password")
      end
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      if @user.update_attributes(permitted_params[:worker])
        redirect_to "/admin/workers/#{@user.id}"
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end
```

But when I get the errors on my validation, I can't see any errors on page, just rendering 'new'. I have tried to something like this

```
   resource = @user
```

But it didn't help.

UPDATE:
My form looks like this:

```
    form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|
      f.inputs "Details" do
        f.input :email, as: :email
        f.input :first_name
        f.input :last_name
        f.input :street_address
        f.input :apt
        f.input :zip_id, :input_html => {:class => 'zip_selector'}
        f.input :phone_number
        f.input :is_active
        f.input :description
        f.input :password, :value => ''
      end
    f.actions
  end
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried  `render 'new', notice: @user.errors.full_messages.join`? This should show notice message on top of page with validation errors.

Comment: I just have tried and nothing happen, also I haven't seen my new inputs value, they are changing to table values. So it's like resource override somewhere